# Grep: Using -w and -o combined

Tags: linux, awk, grep

How can I combine this 2 commands?

`df -m --output=target,size |  grep -w /dbm`

```
/dbm                 394257
```

`df -m --output=target,size|  grep -o '[0-9]\+'`

```
3444
865636
394257
224
```

I want to get the following result:

```
394257
```

And is it possible to multiply the number within 1 command?
For example I want the result(394257) multiplied by 1000 to get the following result:

```
394257000
```

Searched the internet but here I come across python script which I am trying to avoid.
Have read some documentation about Grep but couldnt resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `grep` with `awk` like this:

```bash
df -m --output=target,size | awk '$1 == "/dbm" {print $2 * 1000}'

394257000
```